# NetSuite field type Text Area

Tags: html, tags, textarea, field

Please help me solve this problem:
Why in the field with the type "Text Area" the tags from the arrows are changed, for example "< b >" is replaced by "& lt;B&gt"

I couldn't find any information in the Help Center or in SuiteAnswers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.